# The UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key in the Info.plist is set in such a way that the app will not install on an iPad

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, metadata

I submitted my app for review and received the feedback mentioned in the title.

My project name does not include a "?" anywhere.

Here is my info.plist:

[image]

I tried it using the "armv7" key but that did not work, so I removed it and it still did not work. I have successfully tested it on both iPads and iPhones using TestFlight though!

Comment: Saying it doesn't install on iPad but also saying you tested it on iPad through TestFlight is conflicting.Can you please update the question to be more clear? Make sure to include the steps that you are trying, what is the outcome and what you expect to happen.

Comment: i find it hard to believe an application cant be installed onto an ipad. There must be some overlaying issue / setup you did incorrectly. If you created an xcode project, in your project settings it should be as simple as clicking the 'support ipad' option... You need to clarify your question and provide as much information about your application as possible\

Comment: also, Your 'UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities' key has NO value set

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Above you can see support is ticked off for ipad. 
This is located in your target build settings.
Make sure your project includes this.

Also, make sure your plist actually contains a value. Based on the screenshot you provided, there is no value set.

Should be as simple as that, unless there are other conflicts related to your application that you have not yet divulged in your question.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I tried when I received a similar error:

> We were unable to install the app on iPad. The
> UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key in the Info.plist is set in such a
> way that the app will not install on iPad.
>
> To resolve this issue, please check the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities
> key to verify that it contains only the attributes required for your
> app features or the attributes that must not be present on the device.
> Attributes specified by a dictionary should be set to true if they are
> required and false if they must not be present on the device.

Build Settings > Deployment > Targeted Device Families and make sure you have the devices listed there that you want. Also check iOS Deployment Target is a version of iOS that is supported.

Build Settings > Signing > Code Signing Identity and make sure it is set to iOS Distribution.

I created a new build and submitted that after it was approved on TestFlight and was accepted.

Answer (score 0):

> ios

To add the "telephony" property to the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key in the Info.plist file, follow these steps:

1. Open your Xcode project.
2. In the Project Navigator, select the target for your app.
3. Click on the "Info" tab.
4. Expand the "Custom iOS Target Properties" section.
5. Click the "+" button to add a new key-value pair.
6. Enter "UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities" as the key.
7. Expand the newly added key-value pair.
8. Add a new item to the array by clicking on the "+" button.
9. Enter "telephony" as the item value.
10. Save the changes to the Info.plist file.

Here's a visual representation of the steps described above:

```
<key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
<array>
    <string>telephony</string>
</array>
```

Make sure to review Apple's guidelines and requirements to ensure that adding the "telephony" capability is appropriate for your app and that it complies with their guidelines.

> Ionic Project

To add the "telephony" property to the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key in an Ionic 4 project, you'll need to modify the platform-specific configuration files. Here's how you can do it:

1. Navigate to your Ionic project's root directory in your command line interface.
2. Depending on the platform you're targeting (e.g., iOS), you'll need to locate and edit the corresponding configuration file. For iOS, it would typically be the `config.xml` file located in the `platforms/ios` directory.
3. Open the configuration file (e.g., `config.xml`) using a text editor.
4. Locate the `<platform name="ios">` section (if it doesn't exist, you can add it) within the `<widget>` element.
5. Inside the `<platform name="ios">` section, add the following code:

```xml
<config-file parent="UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities" target="*-Info.plist">
    <array>
        <string>telephony</string>
    </array>
</config-file>
```

This code snippet adds the "telephony" capability to the `UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities` key in the iOS Info.plist file.

6. Save the changes to the configuration file.

Remember to review Apple's guidelines and requirements to ensure that adding the "telephony" capability is appropriate for your app and that it complies with their guidelines.

After making these changes, you can rebuild your Ionic project for the iOS platform, and the "telephony" capability should be included in the resulting app's Info.plist file.